# How to setup fireabse rules with react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm researching how to set up firebase rule with react tho, I haven't resolved this problem for a while.

[fireabse.js]

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/database');
require('firebase/auth');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*************",
  authDomain: "*************.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*************.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "*************",
  storageBucket: "*************.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "*************",
  appId: "*************",
  measurementId: "*************"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

exports.firebaseDb = firebase.database();
exports.ordersDb = firebase.database().ref('/orders');
exports.dateDb = firebase.database().ref('/date');
exports.refDb = firebase.database().ref('/ref');
exports.auth = firebase.auth();
```

[Rules]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "orders":{
      ".indexOn":["orderId","status"],
      "$orderId": {
          ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }        
    },
    "ref":{
      ".indexOn":"orderId"
    } 
  }
}
```

Do you have any examples to solve this problem?

Comment: You can read about realtime database's security rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: None of the code you shared reads from the database yet, so it can't be causing any problems with your security rules.